# Can't link CFugue library correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

I use Visual Studio 2010. I created a new project based on Windows Form Applications template. And now I want to use CFugue. In the main cpp file I included MusicNoteLib.h. In Project Properties I added full path of MusicNote\include to Include Directories at VC++ Directories. Also I added MusicNoteLib.h in Additional Dependencies and wrote a path to it in Additional Library Directories at Linker. But I get errors connect with MIDI functions definitions:

```
MusicGeneration.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100001F) for 'MusicNoteLib.ChannelPressure'; image may not run
MusicGeneration.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000020) for 'MusicNoteLib.ControllerEvent'; image may not run
MusicGeneration.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000021) for 'MusicNoteLib.Instrument'; image may not run
MusicGeneration.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000022) for 'MusicNoteLib.Layer'; image may not run
MusicGeneration.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000023) for 'MusicNoteLib.PitchBend'; image may not run
MusicGeneration.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000024) for 'MusicNoteLib.PolyphonicPressure'; image may not run
MusicGeneration.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000025) for 'MusicNoteLib.Tempo'; image may not run
MusicGeneration.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000026) for 'MusicNoteLib.Time'; image may not run
MusicGeneration.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000027) for 'MusicNoteLib.Voice'; image may not run
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000010) "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnNoteEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,struct MusicNoteLib::Note const *)" (?OnNoteEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBUNote@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000011) "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnVoiceEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::Voice const *)" (?OnVoiceEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVVoice@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000012) "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnTimeEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::Time const *)" (?OnTimeEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVTime@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000013) "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnTempoEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::Tempo const *)" (?OnTempoEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVTempo@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000014) "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnPolyphonicPressureEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::PolyphonicPressure const *)" (?OnPolyphonicPressureEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVPolyphonicPressure@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000015) "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnPitchBendEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::PitchBend const *)" (?OnPitchBendEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVPitchBend@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000016) "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnLayerEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::Layer const *)" (?OnLayerEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVLayer@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000017) "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnKeySignatureEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::KeySignature const *)" (?OnKeySignatureEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVKeySignature@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000018) "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnInstrumentEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::Instrument const *)" (?OnInstrumentEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVInstrument@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000019) "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnControllerEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::ControllerEvent const *)" (?OnControllerEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVControllerEvent@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00001A) "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnChannelPressureEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::ChannelPressure const *)" (?OnChannelPressureEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVChannelPressure@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00002E) "public: void __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIDriverWin32::CloseMIDIOutPort(void)" (?CloseMIDIOutPort@MIDIDriverWin32@jdkmidi@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::EndPlayAsync(void)" (?EndPlayAsync@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00002F) "public: void __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIDriverWin32::StopTimer(void)" (?StopTimer@MIDIDriverWin32@jdkmidi@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::EndPlayAsync(void)" (?EndPlayAsync@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000030) "public: void __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIManager::SeqStop(void)" (?SeqStop@MIDIManager@jdkmidi@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::EndPlayAsync(void)" (?EndPlayAsync@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000037) "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIManager::~MIDIManager(void)" (??1MIDIManager@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::~MIDIRenderer(void)" (??1MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FUAM@XZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000039) "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIDriverWin32::~MIDIDriverWin32(void)" (??1MIDIDriverWin32@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::~MIDIRenderer(void)" (??1MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FUAM@XZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000049) "public: void __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDISequencer::ResetAllTracks(void)" (?ResetAllTracks@MIDISequencer@jdkmidi@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIEventManager::Clear(void)" (?Clear@MIDIEventManager@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00004A) "public: void __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIMultiTrack::Clear(void)" (?Clear@MIDIMultiTrack@jdkmidi@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIEventManager::Clear(void)" (?Clear@MIDIEventManager@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00004B) "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDISequencer::~MIDISequencer(void)" (??1MIDISequencer@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIEventManager::~MIDIEventManager(void)" (??1MIDIEventManager@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAM@XZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00004D) "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIMultiTrack::~MIDIMultiTrack(void)" (??1MIDIMultiTrack@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIEventManager::~MIDIEventManager(void)" (??1MIDIEventManager@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAM@XZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000072) "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDITick::~MIDITick(void)" (??1MIDITick@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDITick::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_EMIDITick@jdkmidi@@$$FUAMPAXI@Z)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000077) "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDISystemExclusive::~MIDISystemExclusive(void)" (??1MIDISystemExclusive@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDISystemExclusive::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_EMIDISystemExclusive@jdkmidi@@$$FUAMPAXI@Z)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDISystemExclusive::~MIDISystemExclusive(void)" (??1MIDISystemExclusive@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDISystemExclusive::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_EMIDISystemExclusive@jdkmidi@@$$FUAMPAXI@Z)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDITick::~MIDITick(void)" (??1MIDITick@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDITick::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_EMIDITick@jdkmidi@@$$FUAMPAXI@Z)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIMultiTrack::~MIDIMultiTrack(void)" (??1MIDIMultiTrack@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIEventManager::~MIDIEventManager(void)" (??1MIDIEventManager@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAM@XZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDISequencer::~MIDISequencer(void)" (??1MIDISequencer@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIEventManager::~MIDIEventManager(void)" (??1MIDIEventManager@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAM@XZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDISequencer::ResetAllTracks(void)" (?ResetAllTracks@MIDISequencer@jdkmidi@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIEventManager::Clear(void)" (?Clear@MIDIEventManager@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIMultiTrack::Clear(void)" (?Clear@MIDIMultiTrack@jdkmidi@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIEventManager::Clear(void)" (?Clear@MIDIEventManager@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIDriverWin32::CloseMIDIOutPort(void)" (?CloseMIDIOutPort@MIDIDriverWin32@jdkmidi@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::EndPlayAsync(void)" (?EndPlayAsync@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIDriverWin32::StopTimer(void)" (?StopTimer@MIDIDriverWin32@jdkmidi@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::EndPlayAsync(void)" (?EndPlayAsync@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIManager::SeqStop(void)" (?SeqStop@MIDIManager@jdkmidi@@$$FQAMXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::EndPlayAsync(void)" (?EndPlayAsync@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FQAMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIDriverWin32::~MIDIDriverWin32(void)" (??1MIDIDriverWin32@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::~MIDIRenderer(void)" (??1MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FUAM@XZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __clrcall jdkmidi::MIDIManager::~MIDIManager(void)" (??1MIDIManager@jdkmidi@@$$FUAM@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::~MIDIRenderer(void)" (??1MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FUAM@XZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnNoteEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,struct MusicNoteLib::Note const *)" (?OnNoteEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBUNote@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnVoiceEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::Voice const *)" (?OnVoiceEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVVoice@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnTimeEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::Time const *)" (?OnTimeEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVTime@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnTempoEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::Tempo const *)" (?OnTempoEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVTempo@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnPolyphonicPressureEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::PolyphonicPressure const *)" (?OnPolyphonicPressureEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVPolyphonicPressure@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnPitchBendEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::PitchBend const *)" (?OnPitchBendEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVPitchBend@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnLayerEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::Layer const *)" (?OnLayerEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVLayer@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnKeySignatureEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::KeySignature const *)" (?OnKeySignatureEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVKeySignature@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnInstrumentEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::Instrument const *)" (?OnInstrumentEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVInstrument@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnControllerEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::ControllerEvent const *)" (?OnControllerEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVControllerEvent@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
MusicGeneration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __clrcall MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::OnChannelPressureEvent(class MusicNoteLib::CParser const *,class MusicNoteLib::ChannelPressure const *)" (?OnChannelPressureEvent@MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@$$FEAMXPBVCParser@2@PBVChannelPressure@2@@Z) referenced in function "void __clrcall `dynamic initializer for 'const MusicNoteLib::MIDIRenderer::`vftable'''(void)" (???__E??_7MIDIRenderer@MusicNoteLib@@6B@@@YMXXZ@?A0x2d87bacc@@$$FYMXXZ)
\\psf\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MusicGeneration\Debug\MusicGeneration.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 44 unresolved externals
```

Example provided with CFugue source code is compiled though.

Comment: Similar elsewhere - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0730e965-7299-44ca-8a95-59e2eb23d153/warning-lnk4248-unresolved-typeref-token-01000017-for-treeitem-image-may-not-run?forum=vclanguage